# Save meta value when WooCommerce order status is completed

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, orders

I made a code to save a value based on a meta key when a certain product is purchased (order status = completed).

I have written the code below to complete this task. However, the meta data does not appear to be saved? Any advice?

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'wpglorify_change_role_on_purchase2' );

function wpglorify_change_role_on_purchase2( $order_id ) {

    // get order object and items
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $items = $order->get_items();
    $user_is= $user->ID;
    $meta_key =  get_field("field");
    $field = get_user_meta($user_is, $meta_key);
    $meta_value = 5;

    $product_id = 1289;

    foreach ( $items as $item ) {

        if( $product_id == $item['product_id'] && $order->user_id ) {
            $user = new WP_User( $order->user_id );

            update_user_meta($user_is, $field, $meta_value, '');

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code contains some mistakes:

- `get_field()` is a ACF function, and doesn't seem to apply here
- You're using `$user->ID;` but `$user` is undefined

Furthermore, it is important to determine whether you want to update **user meta** or **post meta** data

**1)** To update user meta you can use:

```php
// Update user meta
function action_woocommerce_order_status_completed( $order_id, $order ) {
    // Product IDs
    $product_id = 1289;

    // Meta data
    $meta_value = 5;
    $meta_key = 'my_meta_key';

    // Is a order
    if ( is_a( $order, 'WC_Order' ) ) {
        // Getting the user ID
        $user_id = $order->get_user_id();

        // User ID exists
        if ( $user_id >= 1 ) {
            // Loop through order items
            foreach ( $order->get_items() as $key => $item ) {
                // Compare
                if ( $item->get_product_id() == $product_id ) {
                    // Update user meta
                    update_user_meta( $user_id, $meta_key, $meta_value );

                    // Break loop
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'action_woocommerce_order_status_completed', 10, 2 );
```

---

**2)** To update post meta you can use:

```php
// Update post meta
function action_woocommerce_order_status_completed( $order_id, $order ) {
    // Product IDs
    $product_id = 1289;

    // Meta data
    $meta_value = 5;
    $meta_key = 'my_meta_key';

    // Is a order
    if ( is_a( $order, 'WC_Order' ) ) {
        // Loop through order items
        foreach ( $order->get_items() as $key => $item ) {
            // Compare
            if ( $item->get_product_id() == $product_id ) {
                // Add the meta data
                $order->update_meta_data( $meta_key, $meta_value );
                
                // Save
                $order->save();

                /** OR the older way **/
                // update_post_meta( $order_id, $meta_key, $meta_value );

                // Break loop
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'action_woocommerce_order_status_completed', 10, 2 );
```